# How to write a for-loop/if-statement for a dataframe (integer) column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with a column of integers that symbolise birthyears. Each row has 20xx or 19xx in it but some rows have only the xx part.

What I wanna do is add 19 in front of those numbers with only 2 "elemets" if the integer is bigger than 22(starting from 0), or/and add 20 infront of those that are smaller or equal to 22.

This is what I wrote;

```
for x in DF.loc[DF["Year"] >= 2022]:
  x + 1900
  if:
    x >= 22 
  else:
    x + 2000
```

You can also change the code completely, I would just like you to maybe explain what exactly your code does.

Thanks for everybody who takes time to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the rows, use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to change the whole column:

```
y = df["Year"] # just to save typing
df["Year"] = y.where(y > 99, (y + 1900).where(y > 22, y + 2000))
```

or [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
df["Year"][df["Year"].between(0, 21)] += 2000
df["Year"][df["Year"].between(22, 99)] += 1900
```

or [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df["Year"].between(0, 21), "Year"] += 2000
df.loc[df["Year"].between(22, 99), "Year"] += 1900
```

Comment: how exactly does the first version with ".where" work?
wouldn't it add up the values so that 99% of the values besides the one where there is only 2 elements/letters/numbers don't make sense?

Comment: it's a confusing syntax but `a.where(cond, b)` keeps the values in `a` if `cond` is true, but changes to the values in `b` if `cond` is false. So the code says "if y > 99, keep y as it is; else, if y > 22, change it to y + 1900; else, change it to y + 2000".

Answer (score 0):

It is basically what you did, an `if` inside a `for`:

```
new_list_of_years = []
for year in DF.loc[DF["Year"]:
    full_year = year+1900 if year >22 else year+2000
    new_list_of_years.append(full_year)

DF['Year'] = pd.DataFrame(new_list_of_years)
```

**Edit:** You can do that with `for-if` list comprehension also:

```
DF['Year'] = [year+1900 if year > 22 else year+2000 for year in DF.loc[DF["Year"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line with the `apply` method.

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [2002, 95, 1998, 3, 56, 1947]})
print(df)

   date
0  2002
1    95
2  1998
3     3
4    56
5  1947
```

Then:

```py
df = df.date.apply(lambda x: x+1900 if (x<100) & (x>22) else (x+2000 if (x<100)&(x<22) else x) )
```

```py
print(df)

   date
0  2002
1  1995
2  1998
3  2003
4  1956
5  1947
```